# How to create a column with the next value in the list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table as such

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2019 | 50 |
| 1 | 04/01/2019 | 25 |
| 2 | 01/01/2019 | 63 |
| 2 | 15/01/2019 | 43 |

I want to create another column called next_date, and next_value that computes the next date and value grouped by id in the list, so that the new table will look:

| id | date | value | next_date | next_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2019 | 50 | 04/01/2019 | 25 |
| 1 | 04/01/2019 | 25 | None | None |
| 2 | 01/01/2019 | 63 | 15/01/2019 | 43 |
| 2 | 15/01/2019 | 43 | None | None |

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `LEAD()` analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT id, date, value,
       COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar, LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date), 103), 'None') next_date,
       COALESCE(CAST(LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS varchar(max)), 'None') AS next_value
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id, date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim. If I want the max value over the next 7 days, how can I do so?

Comment: Please ask a new question, this one has already been answered.